# output value types from If Else block using Dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I am trying to add value to an outer variable `val_dict` from if and else block in the for loop. The problem is that the output type from if block is different from the output type of else block which throws a type error for either of them if i initialize the variable to one of the output type classes.

In short the `val_dict` is an object that can either be a dictionary<string,object> or a `null object`, but some how i cannot seem to define a common type for both of these object types.

here is the code:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,object>> data_dict =
             new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<(string, string), object> cat_nam_val in dataset) 
{
    var val_dict = new Dictionary<string, object>(); //use val_dict as dictionary or object
    
    if (target_survey_id != null)
    {
        data_dict[target_survey_id].TryGetValue(cat_nam_val.Key.Item1, out val_dict);
    }
    else
    { 
       data_dict.TryGetValue(cat_nam_val.Key.Item1, out val_dict);
    }

    if (IsDictionary(val_dict)); 
    {
        val_dict[cat_nam_val.Key.Item2]  = cat_nam_val.Value; //generate new dict becoz val_dict is an object so cannot be indexed
    }
}
```

Comment: I've cleaned up your commented out code and extra whitespace. That said, it still isn't clear what you are trying to do. There's no indication of what `data_dict` is, where it comes from, or how it is supposed to work. In addition, using a Dictionary as an out param most likely does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks i have added the initialization of ```data_dict``` as well, the problem is that ```val_dict``` could be either a dictionary<string,object> or a ```null object``` depending on the data. I need to create a class that encompasses both of these object types . I am trying to wrap my head around it but failing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot coerce types when using `out`. As a result, you can use a temporary out variable and then cast it if you are certain that it is a dictionary.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<(string, string), object> cat_nam_val in dataset)
{
    var val_dict = new Dictionary<string, object>(); //use val_dict as dictionary or object

    if (target_survey_id != null)
    {
        // use a temporary variable to work around type mismatch
        data_dict[target_survey_id].TryGetValue(cat_nam_val.Key.Item1, out var temp_val_dict);
        
        // if you know that object is a dictionary, cast and assign
        val_dict = (Dictionary<string, object>)temp_val_dict;
    }
    else
    {
        data_dict.TryGetValue(cat_nam_val.Key.Item1, out val_dict);
    }

    if (IsDictionary(val_dict))
    {
        val_dict[cat_nam_val.Key.Item2] = cat_nam_val.Value; //generate new dict becoz val_dict is an object so cannot be indexed
    }
}
```